# NFS export CIFS share

Tags: nfs, cifs

I have a server 192.168.1.1 where a samba share is mounted to /image

I would like to setup an NFS sever on this machine to share the mounted /image folder through NFS.

When I add it to the exports file I get a warning:

exportfs: /image does not support NFS export

So my question is very simple. Is it possible to reshare a samba mount through NFS?
If not then what is the fastest way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The fasted way is to run a NFS server on the system exporting the samba share.

Comment: Which OS is the server running? If it's Unix of some form (and I would assume it was, because you refer to samba) then it'll support NFS. You may need to install an extra package to run NFS. If it's running Windows, then similar applies, but finding an NFS server might be more of a problem. Mounting remote and then re-exporting is dirty, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

NFS only allows exporting local filesystems. From `man exports`:

> The file /etc/exports contains a table of local physical file systems on an NFS server that are accessible to NFS clients.

There is no way around this, you can't re-export remote filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

You should be about to re-export an NFS mount via Samba, but not the other way around like you're trying to do. Stacking will ensure that locks made by Samba are honored in NFS, and will handle complex permissions with less effort. It's also easier to troubleshoot than running the servers on parallel against the same filesystem.

Exporting NFS and Samba without "stacking" them on the same machine will perform much better, but would lack the same degree of locking and permissions cohesion that a stacked configuration would offer. If you don't need to concurrently access the same data via both methods and permissions requirements are simple, this would be better.

Either way isn't ideal. You should endeavor to pick one or the other.